# UnicodeString replace one substring with another

Tags: c++, string, replace, c++builder

I can't find a function that will replace one substring with another.

For example, I have a component `LabeledEdit` and I want to write some text in it. After that, I want to check if there are some spaces in the text and replace them with `%`.

```cpp
String text;
text = LabeledEdit1->Text.Trim();
text = text. <- some replace function to replace " " to "%"
```

Comment: [`StringReplace`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the RTL's [`System::Sysutils::StringReplace()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace) function:

> Replaces occurrences of a substring within a string.
>
> StringReplace replaces occurrences of the substring specified by OldPattern with the substring specified by NewPattern in the string Source.

```cpp
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

String text;
text = LabeledEdit1->Text.Trim();
text = StringReplace(text, _D(" "), _D("%"), TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code

```
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>

String text;
text = LabeledEdit1->Text.Trim();
text = StringReplace(text, _D(" "), _D("%"), TReplaceFlags() << rfReplaceAll);
```

everything working fine